# Different height of maximum and minimum track using react-native-slider

Tags: react-native, slider

At this moment the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@miblanchard/react-native-slider does not have a solution to be able to change the height of the left and right track of the thumb.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

1. The container in which the Slider is should have `overflow style: "hidden"`
2. I use renderThumbComponent to display the thumb left line to the left

   ```
    renderThumbComponent={() => (
      <>
        <View style={styles.thickerLine} />
        <View style={styles.thumb} />
      </>
    )}
   ```
3. I set the style for `thickerLine` to be as long as possible, so that it goes beyond the container.

   ```
    thickerLine: {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 8,
      right: 0,
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      height: 4,
      width: window.width,
    },
   ```

Yes, I know it's wild, but it works!

[image]